# Error Handling not working VBA

Tags: excel, vba, goto

I am trying to loop the user back if it could not find what you were looking for. I have that so far, but how do I loop back to have the user re-enter the info and prompt them with a `MsgBox` as well?

```
Range("A1").Select
Repeat:
Findcata = InputBox("Please Input What Section You Want To Add To")
If Findcata = "" Then Exit Sub
Set RangeObj = Cells.Find(What:=Findcat, After:=ActiveCell, _
    LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
    SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False)
If RangeObj Is Nothing Then GoTo Repeat Else: RangeObj.Select
```

Comment: Is there a typo? `What:=Findcat,` should be `What:=Findcata,`? Try avoid Range Selection in code. So `After:=ActiveCell,` should become `After:=Range("A1"),`. You can make this a **Sub** then `Call ThisSub` in RangeObj Is Nothing.

Comment: Or wrap the entire thing in `Do While RangeObj Is Nothing`

Answer (score 1):

The method below uses `Application.Inputbox` which

- gives the ability to provide a default value
- provides a method to update the `MsgBox` to be clear there is a retry

I have tidied the `Select`, `Find` logic as well.

```
Dim strIn As String
Dim strNew As String
Dim rng1 As Range

Repeat:
strIn = Application.InputBox("Please Input What Section You Want To Add To (Cancel Exits)", strNew, "Default value", , , , , 2)
If strIn = vbNullString Or strIn = "False" Then Exit Sub
Set rng1 = Cells.Find(strIn, ActiveSheet.[a1], xlValues, xlPart, xlByRows, xlNext, False)

If rng1 Is Nothing Then
strNew = "Value not found, please retry"
GoTo Repeat
End If
```